# Locating Old Sakaran Bessarabia near Kishinef

Tags: historical-gazetteer, bessarabia

Trying to find Old Sakaran near Kishinev in Bessarabia.

Comment: Is Sakaran the name of a person or a place?

Comment: I’m assuming that this is a place rather than person you are looking for. Where did you come across this place name?  Can you include an image from a document that mentions it?

Comment: A decent map resource to look at is the 1821 [General Map of Bessarabia](https://www.loc.gov/resource/gdclccn.2018688650/?r=0.399,0.299,0.313,0.133,0) in the Library of Congress collection. The interface allows zooming and panning, so the map can be easily examined. The placenames are in both Russian and French. I had no luck picking out your town, but perhaps you will fare better.

Comment: I downvoted this question because it shows no research effort.  I have closed this question because it has no context.  With place names especially, it is important to know where you saw the name (what document contained it) and the time period when the document was created.  You've effectively blocked us from using any reference material that was created in that period, or that might have been created by the agency that made the document.  

If you want to add more information, please use the edit link under your question.

Comment: Try searching for *Sekaren* (Secareni) in [JewishGen's TownFinder](https://www.jewishgen.org/Communities/jgcd.php). Located 24 miles west to Chisinau.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you can get lucky by searching for town lists. Searching for a town list for Bessarabia leads to a [Jewish Genealogy site](https://www.jewishgen.org/bessarabia/default.asp), which has a [town list alphabetized](https://www.jewishgen.org/bessarabia/GEO_townlist.asp?start=113). The name you list isn't there, *exactly*. But a town whose name seems to close to be a coincidence *is* listed, and that is [Sekareny](https://www.jewishgen.org/bessarabia/GEO_town.asp?id=40). The web site also lists some other names which the town has been known by:

> Other names: Secãreni [Rom], Sekareny [Rus], Sekareni, Sekaren',
> Sakaryany

---

Current spelling and location from Wikipedia is [Secăreni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sec%C4%83reni).

I don't know if the 'old' is relevant, but these sites should give you a little more to work with.